# Unity Card Hover Animations

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, card, prefab

Hello everyone I am trying to make a hover animation to my cards. When you hover over cards in your hand I want them to go up but the card is a prefab so when I hover over one (or click on one) they all go up at the same time. This is a small project for me to practice Trading Card Games and here is the animationless link: https://play.unity.com/mg/other/unitycardtaskbuild

If you have time it would be really nice if you connect with me through discord.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Assuming you are using Canvas and UI elements, take a look at [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1199251/onmouseover-ui-button-c.html), for using Pointer Handler for checking if the mouse is over a card then call a function that will change the local y position.

Comment: I tried to put the prefabs in empty game objects to try single animations with those game objects but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public class MyClass: MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler,IPointerExitHandler
 {
     public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
     {
         //Move your card up
     }
     public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
     {
         //Move your card down
     }
 }
```

Try this Out! I've already written it for you!
By the way, I played your card game and it's cool!
(*´∇`*)

Comment: Thank you so much I updated the game! How can I add drop animations in this game ? I want an animation to kick in when a card is dropped either on the hand or the dropzone.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want exactly, but if you're trying to detect the timing of the mouse lift, try using Input.GetMouseButtonUp ？